# Spring - How to configure OracleDataSource from spring.datasource in application.properties

Tags: java, spring, oracle

In my application.properties i have some `spring.datasource` fields

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE
spring.datasource.username=talon
spring.datasource.password=talon
```

These should be retrieved from a `@Configuration` annotated class

```
@Configuration
public class Db {

    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @NotNull
    private String url;

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Db() {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = null;
        try {
            dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setUser(username);
            dataSource.setPassword(password);
            dataSource.setURL(url);
            dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
            dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
            Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from BOOK");
            rs.next();
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But I'm unable to retrieve the `username` `password` and `url` from there, should I add another annotation somewhere or what am I doing

Like this I have the error:
**java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL**

If I set the proper url with `dataSource.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE");` it can't read the `username` and `password` since they are null  and I have **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**

Comment: you should use `@Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You need to use another annotation in order for your fields to be populated. So annotate the class with `@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")`
2. You cannot initialize your `OracleDataSource` directly in your constructor (i.e. `Db()`) because the properties (your username/password/url fields) are not populated during the call of the constructor, so one thing that you can do is create another method and annotate that with `@PostContruct` in order for your `dataSource` to be correctly created.

An example:

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    // your data source initialization

}
```

One advice would be to change the way to initialize your dataSource and instead of trying to create it inside your constructor, you can rather create a new method which you can annotate with `@Bean` and make it return your dataSource and you can use it later using `@Autowired`.